# Perl: Match specific elements from arrays between two files and print desired elements from the file

Tags: perl

I want to match the elements from arrays between two files. The first file consists of six elements and second file consists of seven elements.

The first six elements in the first file matches with the six elements in the second file.The two lines are identical except for that final element in the second file.

I have to print the entire line from the second file, if the line matches with first file.

First File - **errep.txt**

```
 XYZ432345  Ethiopia    2567    89  ABC P   28-Apr-14
 XYZ432345  Poland      2567    98  ABC P   28-Apr-14
```

Second File - **rep.txt**

```
XYZ432345   Ethiopia    2567    89  ABC P   28-Apr-14   No Issue
XYZ432345   Philippines 2467    92  ADC P   28-Apr-14   No Issue
```

Desired Output

```
XYZ432345   Ethiopia    2567    89  ABC P   28-Apr-14   No Issue
```

Below is the code which I am trying

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(OUT,"> Final Error Report.txt");

open(IN, "rep.txt");
my @values = <IN>;
close IN;
$flag=0;
$count=0;

open(IN, "errep.txt");
my @verify = <IN>;
close IN;

for my $ver (@verify) {
chomp $ver;
@elements= split("\t",$ver);    
 for my $rep (@values) {
 chomp $rep;
 @report = split("\t",$rep);


$newstring1="@elements[0 .. 5]";
$newstring2="@report[0 .. 5]";

if ($newstring1 =~/$newstring2/) {    
    ++$count;
    $flag=1;
}

if($flag==1){
$flag=0;
print OUT "$rep\n";
            }
    }
}
print OUT "Total Count:$count";
```

If any one can improve this code much appreciated. Thanks for suggestions..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you written any perl yet? You need to because we're not really supposed to just write the whole thing for you ...

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Sorry for that, I just updated the code, please guide me regarding this. I m just started learning PERL.

Comment: Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program that you write, and declare all your variables with `my` as close as possible to their first point of use. Please also avoid using variable names `$a` and `$b`, firstly because they are names reserved by Perl's built-in `sort`, and secondly because they aren't at all descriptive and say nothing about the purpose of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

- Logical AND is `&&` not `&` in Perl (and most languages)
- If you want to test for string equality, use e.g. `$code eq $code1` (not `$code =~ $code1`, which does regex matching)
- Using a nested loop is a slow way of doing things, but it might be fast enough if one or both of your input files is fairly small.  But for it to work, you will need to load all the lines from `REPORT` into an array before you start.  Currently, on the second iteration of the outer loop, `<REPORT>` will return `undef` immediately because you have already read everything from this file.  (Alternatively you could rewind the file pointer with `seek()`.)
- Instead of a nested loop you could either use a hashtable, or sort both inputs -- but only bother with doing this if it takes too long.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I just made changes in my code. If you can improve the code much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean *match*. The two lines don't entirely match. Do you mean if the first six elements in the first file match the six elements in the second file? Are the lines identical except for that final element in the seventh file?

Whenever you say "I have to find a match", you think first of using hashes. If your files are very large, you need to think about using an external database.

I'm also going to use more *modern* Perl. This includes `use strict` and `use warnings`. This means declaring variables with `my`. This catches many of the programming errors that you run into.

I create a hash called `%file_hash`. The key to this hash will be the file with the fields separated by colons instead of spaces. This way, I don't have to worry about space differences between the two files since the fields will be in the same order.

The data of this hash will be the line itself. For example:

```
$file_hash{XYZ432345:Ethiopia:2567:89:ABC:P:28-Apr-14} =
   "XYZ432345   Ethiopia    2567    89  ABC P   28-Apr-14   No Issue"
```

Now, if I do the same for the second file, I can see if that key exists in `%file_hash`. If it does, I know I've seen that line before in File #1, and I'll print out that data.

By using a hash, I only have to go through each file once instead of matching each line against each other. If file #1 contains 100 lines, and file #2 contains 200 lines, I'm going through 300 iterations. In your way, you're looping 100 * 200 times, or 2000 iterations.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;  # Will kill my program if file doens't open
use feature qw(say);

use constant {
    file_1  => 'rep.txt',
    file_2  => 'errep.txt',
};

#
# Open file #1 and build the hash index
#
open my $fh_1, '<', file_1;

my %file_hash;
while ( my $line = <$fh_1> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my $key = substr( $line, 0, 53);
    $key =~ s/\s+/:/g;
    $file_hash{$key} = $line;
}
close $fh_1;

#
# Open file #2 and compare the lines against that hash index
#
open my $fh_2, '<', file_2;
while ( my $line = <$fh_2> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my $key = $line;
    $key =~ s/\s+/:/g;
    if ( $file_hash{$key} ) {
        say "$file_hash{$key};"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to get the output from the above script. I just updated the new script that i m using.. there i m facing a challenge to move on to the next line. Please guide me..

Comment: I modified the program to change spaces to a single `:`. This way, you don't depend upon the spacing for the keys. I used the two files you presented in your program and used the file names you gave. The script should work with the data you gave here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use something like this. Note the following

- `use strict` and `use warnings`, and the declaration of all variables with `my`
- Meaningful variable names
- Lexical file handles instead of global ones (`my $rep_fh` instead of `INFILE`) etc.
- I have copied the contents of `rep.txt` into the array `@rep`, to save reopening the file multiple times
- I have left the fields in their *arrays*, and used the `all` function from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::Util) to check whether all of the first six fields match. There is no need to copy the values to their own scalar variables if you're not using them separately.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'all';

open my $rep_fh,  '<', 'rep.txt' or die qq{Unable to open "rep.txt" for input: $!};
my @rep = <$rep_fh>;
chomp @rep;
close $rep_fh;

open my $errep_fh, '<', 'errep.txt' or die qq{Unable to open "errep.txt" for input: $!};

while (my $errep_record = <$errep_fh>) {

  chomp $errep_record;
  my @errep_record = split /\t/, $errep_record;

  for my $rep_record (@rep) {

    my @rep_record = split /\t/, $rep_record;

    if ( all { $rep_record[$_] eq $errep_record[$_] } 0 .. 5 ) {
      print "$rep_record\n";
    }
  }
}
```